# Cannot handle STDOUT and STDERR output properly with popen3?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a function to execute a shell command, and returns its exit code, STDOUT and STDERR.

The problem is, this function cannot capture STDOUT and STDERR output properly.

```
def sh(*args)
  options = args[-1].respond_to?(:to_hash) ? args.pop.to_hash: {}
  options = { :timeout => 0, :sudo => false }.merge(options)
  cmd = options[:sudo] == false ? args[0] : "sudo " << args[0]

  begin
    stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3(cmd)
    pid = wait_thr[:pid]
    out_buf = ""
    err_buf = ""
    start = Time.now

    # Manually ping the process per 0.2 second to check whether the process is alive or not
    begin
      out_buf << stdout.read_nonblock(4096)
      err_buf << stderr.read_nonblock(4096)
      # kill the process if it timeouts
      if options[:timeout] != 0 && (Time.now - start) > options[:timeout]
        Process.kill("KILL", pid)
        Process.detach(pid)
        raise RuntimeError, "process with pid #{pid} timed out with #{options[:timeout]} seconds."
      end
      sleep 0.2
    rescue IO::WaitReadable, EOFError
    end while wait_thr.alive?

  rescue => e
    NtfLogger.warn("sh '#{args}' executed with failure: #{e}")

  ensure
    if wait_thr.nil?
      return 1, out_buf, err_buf
    else
      return wait_thr.value.exitstatus, out_buf, err_buf
    end
  end
end # end of sh
```

Could anybody please help me figure out what the problem is?

Comment: what do you mean by 'cannot capture' here? does it timeout, what?

Comment: I meant it often lose some text from stdout and stderr.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding of `popen3`'s docs are that it's better to do the processing within a block:

```
Open3.popen3([env,] cmd... [, opts]) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  pid = wait_thr.pid # pid of the started process.
  ...
  exit_status = wait_thr.value # Process::Status object returned.
end
```

In non-block form, the docs note that the streams must be closed:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3([env,] cmd... [, opts])
pid = wait_thr[:pid]  # pid of the started process.
...
stdin.close  # stdin, stdout and stderr should be closed explicitly in this form.
stdout.close
stderr.close
exit_status = wait_thr.value  # Process::Status object returned.
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3

Lastly, FWIW, here's a wrapper around `capture3` which I use on my end. You could easily extend it to add a `sudo` option, in case the thread-related parts of your `sh` utility aren't critical:

```
#
# Identical to Open3.capture3, except that it rescues runtime errors
#
# @param env optional (as `Kernel.system')
# @param *cmd the command and its (auto-escaped) arguments
# @param opts optional a hash of options (as `Kernel.system')
#
# @return [stdout, stderr, success] | [$/, $/, nil] on error
#
def system3(*cmd)
  begin
    stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(*cmd)
    [stdout, stderr, status.success?]
  rescue
    [$/, $/, nil]
  end
end
```

Comment: An important feature of my wrapper is to check the execution time limitation. If I the command cannot finish within certain limit, I'll kill it. But the `system3` wrapper doesn't have that feature.

Comment: @EvanLi: yup. Per my own comment: "in case the thread-related parts of your sh utility aren't critical"… In that case, my understanding is you must close the streams before actually using and reading anything out of them.

Comment: Is that true? I tried to close stdin, stdout and stderr before `out_buf << stdout.read_nonblock(4096)`, but I got exception that `closed stream`.

Comment: The two `popen3` bits of code I highlighted above are straight from the Ruby docs, along with a link.

Comment: But frankly, seeing that you're re-inventing a weird version of `Thread.join` for all intents and purposes, methinks you should give a more serious thought to using `capture3` as I suggest at the end of my answer.

Comment: I don't quite understand your last comment. What did you mean about `Thread.join`? With `capture3`, how to implement time limitation?